# How to disable thumbnail generation in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an alfresco 3.4.d instance that seems to have a problem with content transformation while trying to generate thumbnails for PDF.

**Is there a *fast way* to disable thumbnail generation in order to confirm my suspicions?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable the Share thumbnails generation, you can set the following **property** in `alfresco-global.properties`:

```
system.thumbnail.generate=false
```

You can also turn off selected mimetype thumbnail generation using the `mimetypeMaxSourceSizeKBytes` property. If the value **(KB)** is less than zero, a thumbnail will be generated regardless of size. A value of **0** turns `off` thumbnail generation for a given **mimetype**.

You can check here too :

```
### Thumbnail maximum size limits (KB)
###
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.pdf=-1
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.txt=-1
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.docx=-1
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.xlsx=0
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.pptx=0
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.odt=0
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.ods=0
system.thumbnail.mimetype.maxSourceSizeKBytes.odp=0
```